# firebase generates notification automatically

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

I am using GCM in my android application, to start my `GcmIntentService` service I have `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

If the application is in foreground, everything works ok. But if the application runs in background, extra notification is generated, when I check `logcat` logs, there are messages from `Firebase`

> 09-22 14:10:56.392 28401-29137/com.myapp.android.debug
>   W/FirebaseMessaging: Icon resource myicon not found. Notification will
>   use app icon.

Comment: seems same, but i don't use FCM for my app

Comment: FCM is the new name for GCM, they are the same product

Comment: But need different configuration

Comment: Yes different implementation in the app, but behind the scenes it works the same

Comment: Generally, it is unclear for me why firebase is called,while I don't have any references in gradle file

Comment: The problem was in google play services , we downgraded version to 8.4  and it fixed. But that is not a solution :(